# List of figures with bookdown::word_document2 and rmarkdown

Tags: ms-word, r-markdown, bookdown

Is there a way of creating a list of figures/tables with bookdown and Rmarkdown when outputting to word_document2?

With the pdf/latex, adding to the yaml header works:

`lot: true
lof: true`

But I can't figure out how to have it in a word document.

Comment: Word is by far the most limited output format for R Markdown, as it is not an open source language like HTML and PDF outputs. From what I know, this is not possible.

Comment: You may want to try bookdownplus. Goodluck. https://bookdown.org/baydap/bookdownplus/quickstart.html#more-output-formats